# php image upload with jquery post

Tags: php, jquery, image-uploading, image-upload

ı want to upload image with jquery post. ı dont want to use form.

the problem is ı just got image name, ı cant use this:

```
 $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

 $copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
```

my jquery function:

```
$('#add').click(function(){

    var image=$('#image').val();


    $.post(
            'select.php?p=up',
            {img:image},
            function(answer){

                $('#sonuc').html(answer);
            }
    );

});
```

html code:

```
<form name="newad" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="" id="form">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="file" name="image" id="image"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="Submit" type="button" value="Upload" id="add"></td></tr>
</table>    
</form>
```

not: it works when ı submit form but it doesnt work like this, and ı have to do this.

Comment: This question has already been asked here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using jsupload plugin for this purpose. Your javascript would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#uploadbutton").jsupload({ 
    action: "addFile.do",
    onComplete: function(response){
      alert( "server response: " + response);
    }   
});
```