# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation Simple post function

Tags: php, jquery, post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$.post throwing “Illegal invocation ”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729442/post-throwing-illegal-invocation)

I am getting this error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation.

And when i expand it i get these errors.

> - upload test.js:53
> - (anonymous function) test.js:42

Here is my code.

```
$("#continue").click(function() {
    upload();
    alert("clicked");
    return false;
});


function upload(){
      $.post('http://127.0.0.1/web/upload/', {
            image_src:image_src,
            page_domain:page_domain,
            product_name:productName
      }, function(data){
        $("#MAIN").html(data);
      })
    return false;
    }
```

I have looked at other versions of this error over stackoverflow but none seem to have a working answer for my code. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Too little code. This one seems fine.

Comment: What's on line 53 & 42 ?

Comment: 53 :    $.post('http://127.0.0.1/web/upload/', { and 42 is  $("#MAIN").hide();

Comment: sorry, on line 42 is upload();

Answer (score 0):

It is not that simple to upload image (files in general) data using "ajax" call. Check this answer for more information [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) and [php image upload with jquery post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991471/php-image-upload-with-jquery-post)

Comment: I'm not uploading it using ajax, Im just simply sending the path of the image to my current upload script.

Comment: @user1527354 Where are you getting "image_src" and is it of type "String"?

Comment: its from image_src = image.attr("src"); so basically its just the src value of a <img> tag.

Comment: Since I can't see how are your variables initialised, I suggest you modify your post to use first hardcoded "string" values, and use only console.log(data) to check response instead of inserting with .html() since I don't know what is your server returning (data type).