# $.post throwing "Illegal invocation "

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Edit: None of the answers suggested so far have worked at all.

I'm running this call with django. The first time it runs, the server returns "n_usr" (which changes the form the user files in). The second time, it just throws an `Illegal invocation` error.

```
function log_in () {

        username = $('#usr_enter').val();
        password = $('#pass_enter').val();
        if(!n_usr){
            $.post('/ajax/login',{password: password, username: username}, function(data) {
              if(data == "n_usr"){
                $('#new_user_entry').show('slow');
                n_usr = true;
              }
              else {

              }

            })
    }else {
        password2 = $('#pass_re_enter');
        penname = $('#pen_enter');
            $.post('/ajax/login', {password: password, password2: password2, username: username, pen_name: penname, TN: "TN"}, function(data) {
                if(data == "e_act"){

                } else {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Illegal invocation` means that you are calling a function in the wrong context.

Comment: @Rocket what do you mean by context?

Comment: Like trying to call `console.log.call(document, 'test')`.  That's calling `console.log` in the context of `document`.  Or `setTimeout(someFunc)`.

Comment: @Rocket Ok. Do you know specifically what I'm calling that is in the wrong context?

Comment: Yep, I figured it out!  You forgot `.val()` :-P

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your `else`, you have:

```
password2 = $('#pass_re_enter');
penname = $('#pen_enter');
```

Then you have:

```
{password: password, password2: password2, username: username, pen_name: penname, TN: "TN"}
```

You are getting `Illegal invocation` because jQuery is trying to serialize the jQuery object for `$.post`, and it can't.  It's probably trying to call a string method, and is passing it a jQuery object as context, thus causing the error.

You need to add `.val()`.

```
password2 = $('#pass_re_enter').val();
penname = $('#pen_enter').val();
```

Comment: What I was going to suggest as well.

Comment: I love you. I had a similar error and for some reason I forgot to add a parameter with ".val()", I was getting the most weird errors. After an hour, I made it right! I always do the most little errors..it takes a lot of attention. Tjìhank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well you are not calling them the same -- the first time:

```
 $.post(url_base+'/ajax/login' ...
```

and the 2nd

```
  $.post('/ajax/login', {....
```

Change the 2nd one to include url_base.

Comment: url_base is an empty string that I thought I had removed from the program. Adding it to the 2nd call does not change anything. Thanks though.